# php mysql_fetch_object Please help me i am not sure where i am going wrong

Tags: php

```
<?php 
if  (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $fname = $_POST['fname'];
      $sname = $_POST['sname'];
      $tellno = $_POST['tellno'];
      $mobno = $_POST['mobno'];
      $homeadd = $_POST['homeadd'];
      $busadd = $_POST['busadd'];
      echo "ok";

      $select_details = mysql_query("select * from cont_info WHERE email='$email'");
      $fetch_details = mysql_fetch_object($select_details);

            $p_email = $fetch_details->email;
            $p_fname = $fetch_details->fname;
            $p_sname = $fetch_details->sname;
            echo $p_email . $p_fname;   

            if ($select_details == TRUE) {
                echo $email .'is associated with ' .$P_fname;
            }else{
                if ($email == ""){
                    echo " Enter email address";

                }else {
        mysql_query("insert into `cont_info` (fname, sname, email, tellno, mobno, homeadd, busadd) values ('$fname', '$sname', '$email', '$tellno', '$mobno', '$homeadd', '$busadd')");

              }
            }
}else { echo "enter all fields"; }  
?>
```

Error messages:

Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /var/www/html/reg/test.php on line 38

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/reg/test.php on line 40

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/reg/test.php on line 41

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/reg/test.php on line 42

Comment: $fetch_details = mysql_fetch_object($select_details);

Comment: why are you using mysql it old method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to next

```
    <?php

if  (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $fname = $_POST['fname'];
      $sname = $_POST['sname'];
      $tellno = $_POST['tellno'];
      $mobno = $_POST['mobno'];
      $homeadd = $_POST['homeadd'];
      $busadd = $_POST['busadd'];
      echo "ok";

      $select_details = mysql_query("select * from cont_info WHERE email='$email'");
      if ($select_details === false) {
       die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
       }
      $fetch_details = mysql_fetch_object($select_details);

            $p_email = $fetch_details->email;
            $p_fname = $fetch_details->fname;
            $p_sname = $fetch_details->sname;
            echo $p_email . $p_fname;   

            if ($select_details == TRUE) {
                echo $email .'is associated with ' .$P_fname;
            }else{
                if ($email == ""){
                    echo " Enter email address";

                }else {
        mysql_query("insert into `cont_info` (fname, sname, email, tellno, mobno, homeadd, busadd) values ('$fname', '$sname', '$email', '$tellno', '$mobno', '$homeadd', '$busadd')");

              }
            }
      }else {
        echo "enter all fields";
      }

?>
```

because  mysql_query can return FALSE